# Python print is list but return not list with while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-requests, return

```
isActiveData = isActive["Data"]
    isActiveDataLen = len(isActiveData)

    if isActiveDataLen > 0:
        while isActiveDataLen > 0:
            isActiveDataLen -= 1
            print (isActiveDataLen)
```

Result

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

```
if isActiveDataLen > 0:
        while isActiveDataLen > 0:
            isActiveDataLen -= 1
            return (isActiveDataLen)
```

Result

10

I have a program like this. But with print, I can extract the numbers I want from the while loop. When I use return, the while loop only works once and I cannot continue the program. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: you're printing 11 numbers on the first snippet. it's not clear which one of them you want it to return

Comment: I'd advise you to checkout keyword yield. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do#answers this post explaines it, as well as generators.

Comment: this is the expected behavior of the `return` statement. What do you want to do with the data? do you want to return all of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `return` statement, the function stops and returns a value. If you want to extract a given number you can put it in an `int` for example and then return it at the end of your loop. Or if you want to return multiple values you can return a tuple with all the values you need to return (still at the end of your loop)

Comment: Yes, but the data here can be a different value each time a variable function is run. I have tried many times how I can return it as a tuple in this way.